# sendKeys not working for input (numeric keypad on Samsung ) working with Appium and Java

Tags: java, android, appium

```
driver.findElement(By.id("com.volker.android.volkerforms:id/pin1")).sendKeys("1234");

        //numinp.sendKeys("1234");
driver.findElement(By.id("com.volker.android.volkerforms:id/login")).click();
```

I tried

```
 //capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.volker.android.volkerforms");
        //capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.volker.android.volkerforms.ui.LoginActivity");
```

Comment: Is the same code working on other devices? of the same android version? and with the same keyboard settings?

Comment: The `{}` button on the editor can format your codes.

Comment: Thanks all for your help i will shortly get back to you . I have taken your suggestions on board.

Answer (score 0):

Basically uiautomatorviewer shows you the full structure for the id locators and you should not add entire locator structure for `By.id`.

Use below snippet and it should work.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("pin1")).sendKeys("1234");
driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
```

Comment: Srinu,  Thanks I will try and get back to you shortly.